# Adding tooltip to groupbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, forms, .net-3.5, outlook-2010

After reading the descriptions of every property, I just can't find anything to define a tooltip in the groupbox class, or textbox or listview. Can I ask for a link to put me on the right track?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To define tooltips, you first need to drag a ToolTip component on the from from the toolbox. Then every control will have addition tooltip text properties. You can also do that manually:

```
ToolTip toolTip1 = new ToolTip();
toolTip1.SetToolTip(this.groupBox1, "My groupBox1 tooltip!");
toolTip1.SetToolTip(this.checkBox1, "My checkBox1 tooltip!");
```

See the msdn article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.aspx).

Comment: thanks! :) The designer isn't very clear on how to assign tooltips to objects, I prefer to do it via code.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `ToolTip` control to the form. Drag and drop from the Toolbox.
2. Go to the properties of the group box and set property `Tool Tip on toolTip1` to the desired tooltip text (toolTip1 is the name of your tooltip control).